# Problems on NodeJs, GitHub and IONIC connection by proxy

Tags: node.js, github, proxy, ionic-framework

My contribution

I can't download dependencies on my job
I have error connection , by the proxy problems

Comment: PEEFECT i didn't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my contribution

Install any package from NodeJs when you work on a company, and this company has a proxy, those line solve my life on my job. I hope be useful:

```
// when you have a package.json and you need install all
npm --proxy http://<your_account>:<your_password>@<ip_address>:<port_number> install

// Set as an environment proxy
npm config set proxy http://<your_account>:<your_password>@<ip_address>:<port_number>
npm config set https-proxy http://<your_account>:<your_password>@<ip_address>:<port_number>


// this is when you have some packages(dependencies) and those are stored on Github
git config --global http.proxy http://<your_account>:<your_password>@<ip_address>:<port_number>
git config --global https.proxy http://<your_account>:<your_password>@<ip_address>:<port_number>

// if you start with IONIC you will need set on the environment the proxy
set PROXY=http://<your_account>:<your_password>@<ip_address>:<port_number>
```

See you all